# POSTGRES: problems on functions

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql

So, Im trying to work on a simple book loans system and Im having problems on creating and using a function.

I have a Loans 'Table', Copies 'Table' and Available 'View'.

"Available View" looks like this:

```
 book_id | available_copies
---------+------------------
 BI6     |                1
```

wherein 'available_copies' column is

```
COUNT(copy_id) AS available_copies 
FROM copies 
WHERE copy_id NOT IN (SELECT copy_id FROM loans)
```

This is my "Copies Table"

```
 copy_id | book_id | copy_no | copy_code
---------+---------+---------+-----------
 CI8     | BI6     |       8 | CI
 CI9     | BI6     |       9 | CI
 CI7     | BI7     |       7 | CI
 CI10    | BI7     |      10 | CI
```

and this is my "Loans Table"

```
 loan_id | copy_id | user_id | borrow_date |  due_date  | loan_no | loan_code
---------+---------+---------+-------------+------------+---------+-----------
 LI10    | CI10    | UI4     | 2013-05-21  | 2013-05-26 |      10 | LI
 LI11    | CI8     | UI4     | 2013-05-21  | 2013-05-26 |      11 | LI
 LI12    | CI7     | UI4     | 2013-05-22  | 2013-05-27 |      12 | LI
```

What i really wanted to do is.. if the available_copies is 0 (like in the "available view" above, BI7 is not in the Available View anymore because all copies where already borrowed) postgres will prompt something that you cannot borrow books in Loans anymore since the book is already out of copies.

Im kinda new to plpgsql. Please help. :(

Comment: **ALWAYS** show your exact PostgreSQL version. See `select version()`.

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit

Comment: There's no way the code in the unedited question could possibly have run, then, it fails to even compile.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Pg version you has, but probably some older. I see lot of bugs in your example - so I don't believe it was accepted by postgres

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION try(copyID TEXT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT available_copies FROM available -- missing INTO ??? 
    -- Undeclared variable "available_copies" and probably
    -- collision with column named "available_copies" 
    IF available_copies > 0 THEN 
       INSERT INTO loans(copy_id) VALUES(copyID);
       RETURN BOOLEAN; --- RETURN true or false, but BOOLEAN??
    ELSE
       RETURN BOOLEAN;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Believe me, It was accepted by postgres and I cant believe it either thats why I asked. HAHAHA. Im using psql 9.2. I dont have any background on plpgsql I kinda rushed things out. Are there any ways you can think of on how solve my problem??

Comment: @user2406280: Your information is impossible. The script in your question cannot be executed as it is. There must be some kind of misunderstanding.

Comment: Oh, Is that so?? Well, if its impossible, then, are there any ways on how i can check the availability of the book through plpgsql functions?? Sorry for bothering, I'm really new to plpgsql.

Comment: @user2406280 The are plenty of ways to check availability of the book through plpgsql functions. He just says, that the function code you provided is invalid.

Comment: Yes, I know. But can you give me an example??

Comment: @user2406280 "CREATE FUNCTION" not giving an error isn't the same as it actually running. You should really show the *exact text* of any error messages you get in future. (This wouldn't be accepted by CREATE FUNCTION in a modern PostgreSQL either, as it'd fail PL/PgSQL syntax checking).

Answer (score 0):

Example of PL/SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION try(copyID TEXT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN NOT EXISTS (SELECT l.copy_id FROM loans l WHERE l.copy_id = copyID);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It will `RETURN` `TRUE` if the record with `copyID` `NOT EXISTS` in `loans`;

Same function as SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION try(copyID TEXT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
    SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT l.copy_id FROM loans l WHERE l.copy_id = copyID)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: if i enter a copy_id that is already in the loans table, will this function immediately work?? It doesn't need anything to make it work??

Comment: It only rely on table `loans` with field `copy_id`.

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work?? Maybe because all "copy_id"s were results of concatenated columns, copy_code(char) and copy_no(serial)??

Comment: Without any error messages or explanations how it `doesnt work` I can only guess.

Comment: There are no error messages at all. It just accepts same copy_ids even after I put the example you have posted.

Comment: Where does "it" accepts copy_ids and where have you "put" the example? Try reading some basic manuals on how postgres works and how to use functions and triggers.

Comment: Well I tried to insert it in the table?? I tried to execute it in sql queries?? Do you know some useful plpgsql aside from the manual that postgres provided?? Because everytime i search some it only directs me to postgres manual.

Comment: Search engine you are using does a correct thing. Postgers official manual is all you need now. The other books, manuals and mailing lists are for things you dont need atm.